# MySQL Inserts 0 instead of variable value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert `$userid` to my database but instead of inserting the user id it inserts 0. When I `echo $user['id'];` it returns the user id.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    // Validate the file type
    $userid = trim(sanitize($user['id'])); //GOD DAMMIT HELP HERE
    $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'rar', 'zip', 'exe'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $ext = trim(sanitize($fileParts['extension']));
    $file_name = trim(sanitize($_FILES['Filedata']['name']));
    $file_size = trim(sanitize(format_bytes($_FILES['Filedata']['size'])));

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (userid, name, ext, size) VALUES ('$userid', '$file_name', '$ext', '$file_size')"); //Upload the file and add to MySQL
        $fileid = mysql_insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/$fileid." .$fileParts['extension']);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

$user['id'] function

```
  //Use $user['value'] to retrieve data
  if ($_SESSION['username'] != null) {
    $u_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT 1");
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($u_query);
  }
```

var_dump of $user

```
array(20) { [0]=> string(2) "14" ["id"]=> string(2) "14" [1]=> string(4) "test" ["username"]=> string(4) "test" [2]=> string(128) "f94f06eac339c5c59685d008318b88cf74d047742cca202271a49ac90c44e0ca4e0953c57b5dcf589b3deeedd04a3d0807ba134c3e0cf0e371066e69ae92d22e" ["password"]=> string(128) "f94f06eac339c5c59685d008318b88cf74d047742cca202271a49ac90c44e0ca4e0953c57b5dcf589b3deeedd04a3d0807ba134c3e0cf0e371066e69ae92d22e" [3]=> string(14) "test@gmail.com" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@gmail.com" [4]=> string(14) "test@gmail.com" ["ppemail"]=> string(14) "test@gmail.com" [5]=> string(0) "" ["ip"]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(1) "0" ["banned"]=> string(1) "0" [7]=> string(0) "" ["reason"]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" [9]=> string(8) "28127712" ["code"]=> string(8) "28127712" }
```

Comment: What are the contents of `$user`?  Do a `var_dump`.

Comment: Print the query that is executed before executing it. I.e., what is the value of `$userid`?

Comment: I edited the post with the var_dump of $user

Comment: Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sanitize()`. Are you sure you're using it correctly? I imagine that `$userid` is empty...

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your field is numeric, therefore then since you would be giving a string instead (you use quotes around your userid in the query parameter for '$userid') mysql assumes 0...

Comment: MySQL will do the type conversion automatically.